# User always null and IsAuthenticated false, ASP.NET Identity with JWT

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-identity

I have a big problem with an app in ASP.NET and VueJS, using ASP.NET Core Identity. When the user has logged in,

I can create the JWT token but User is always Null and the IsAuthenticated property is always False. Context should be retreive User and isAuthenticated but there are both Null and false.

I tried using [Authorize] after Context controller, the server always responds 404.

Startup.cs

```
namespace webapi
{
    public class Startup
    {
        public const string JWTAuthScheme = "JWTAuthScheme";
        public static readonly SymmetricSecurityKey SecurityKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.Default.GetBytes("LoremIpsumDolorSitAmetConsecteturAdpiscingElit"));

        public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }

        public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddCors();
            // Gestione DB
            services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
           options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));


           services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
                .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

            
            services.AddAuthorization();

            services.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
                .AddJwtBearer(options =>
                {
                    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                    {
                        LifetimeValidator = (before, expires, token, param) =>
                        {
                            return expires > DateTime.UtcNow;
                        },
                        ValidateAudience = false,
                        ValidateIssuer = false,
                        ValidateActor = false,
                        ValidateLifetime = true,
                        IssuerSigningKey = SecurityKey,
                        AuthenticationType = "ApplicationCookie"
                    };

                    // Add this at the end:
                    options.Events = new JwtBearerEvents
                    {
                        OnAuthenticationFailed = context =>
                        {
                            // Put a breakpoint here
                            System.Console.WriteLine(context.Exception);
                            return Task.CompletedTask;
                        },
                    };
                });

            //services.AddAuthentication("Bearer").AddJwtBearer();

            services.AddSignalR();
            services.AddMvc();

        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting.IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseHsts(); //Forza HTTPS
            }

            app.UseCors(builder => builder
            .WithOrigins("https://localhost:5173")
            .AllowAnyMethod()
            .AllowAnyHeader()
            .AllowCredentials()
            );

            app.UseRouting(); // Aggiungi questa riga per attivare il routing dei controller

            app.UseAuthentication();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints =>
            {
                endpoints.MapControllers(); // Registra i controller
            });

        }



    }
}
```

AccountController.cs

```
namespace webapi.Controllers
{

    public class UserCredentials
    {
        public string Username { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }

    [Route("[Controller]")]
    public class AccountController : Controller
    {
        private static readonly SigningCredentials SigningCreds = new SigningCredentials(Startup.SecurityKey, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);
        private readonly JwtSecurityTokenHandler _tokenHandler = new JwtSecurityTokenHandler();

        private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;
        private readonly SignInManager<ApplicationUser> _signInManager;

        public AccountController(UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,SignInManager<ApplicationUser> signInManager)
        {
            _userManager = userManager;
            _signInManager = signInManager;
        }

        /*
         *  Controller di Registazione
         */

        [HttpPost("register")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] UserCredentials creds)
        {



            // Verifica se l'utente esiste già
            var existingUser = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(creds.Username);
            if (existingUser != null)
            {
                return Json(new { error = "L'utente esiste già." });
            }

          

            // Crea un nuovo utente
            var newUser = new ApplicationUser
            {
                UserName = creds.Username,
            };

            // Registra il nuovo utente
            var result = await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, creds.Password);

            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                // Esegui il login del nuovo utente
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(newUser, isPersistent: false);

                return Json(new
                {
                    name = newUser.UserName,
                    role = "User"
                });
            }
            else
            {

                List<string> errorMessages = new List<string>();

                // Itera attraverso gli errori e li aggiunge alla lista
                foreach (var error in result.Errors)
                {
                    errorMessages.Add(error.Description);
                }

                // Restituisci la lista di errori come JSON
                return Json(errorMessages);
            }
        }

        /*
         *   Controller di Login
         */



        [HttpPost("JwtLogin")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> JwtLogin([FromBody] UserCredentials creds)
        {
            // Verifica le credenziali dell'utente con ASP.NET Core Identity
            var user = await _userManager.FindByNameAsync(creds.Username);
            if (user == null || !await _userManager.CheckPasswordAsync(user, creds.Password))
            {
                return Json(new { error = "Username o password errati. Riprova." });
            }

   

            // Genera il token JWT
            var token = GenerateJwtToken(user);
            

            return Json(new
            {
                token = token,
                auth = User?.Identity.IsAuthenticated

            });
        }

        private string GenerateJwtToken(ApplicationUser user)
        {
            var claims = new[]
            {
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, user.UserName),
                new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User"),
     
            };


            //var key = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("7dqbkWwR8zNrUH727dqbkWwR8zNrUH72"));
            //var creds = new SigningCredentials(key, SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256);



            var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
                "VueAspAuth",
                "VueAspAuth",
                claims,
                expires: DateTime.UtcNow.AddDays(30),
                signingCredentials: SigningCreds
            );

            return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
        }

        /*
         *   Controller di Logout
         */
        [HttpPost("logout")]
        [Authorize]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Logout()
        {
            await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
            return StatusCode(200);
        }


        [HttpGet("context")]

        public JsonResult Context()
        {
            var userName = this.User.Identity.Name; // Ottieni lo username dell'utente
            var userRole = this.User.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Role); // Ottieni il ruolo dell'utente

            string customHeaderValue = HttpContext.Request.Headers["Authorization"];

            

            return Json(new
            {
                username = userName,
                role = userRole,
                auth = this.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated,
                tok = customHeaderValue
            });
        }

        //private bool userValidation(UserCredentials creds)
        //{
        //    bool retVal = creds.Email == "mail@example.com" ? true : false;
        //    return retVal;
        //}

        private ClaimsPrincipal GetPrincipal(UserCredentials creds, string authScheme)
        {
            var claims = new List<Claim>
            {
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, creds.Username), 
                 new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "User")
            };

            return new ClaimsPrincipal(new ClaimsIdentity(claims, authScheme));
        }

    }
}
```

I have a big problem with an app in ASP.NET and VueJS, using ASP.NET Core Identity. When the user has logged in,

I can create the JWT token but User is always Null and the IsAuthenticated property is always False. Context should be retreive User and isAuthenticated but there are both Null and false.

I tried using [Authorize] after Context controller, the server always responds 404.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I tried using [Authorize] after Context controller, the server always
> responds 404.

Without adding the Authorize attribute, it will navigate to the related page, right?  Generally, if authentication failures, it will return a 401status code with the message "Unauthorized, instead of the 404 error. So please check the request URL, whether the URL is correct or not?

> I can create the JWT token but User is always Null and the
> IsAuthenticated property is always False

About the above error, you are using the JwtLogin method, right? When this method is called, the user is not logged in, so the HttpContext.User is null and IsAuthenticated is false.

To get the check whether a user is authenticated after a successful login by using the `User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` property. In the `JwtLogin` method, you can use `_signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync` to check whether the user is logged in success, after that check the user is authenticated or not, code like this:

```
        var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(model.Email, model.Password, model.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);

        if (result.Succeeded)
        {
            // User has successfully logged in
            // You can check if the user is authenticated here
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                // User is authenticated, you can redirect or perform other actions.
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
        }
```